# Image not populating on Header in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, react-native

I am trying to get an image appear on my header in the iOS simulator, but it is not working.  I am being told said files that the files for my image and where it lives do not exist.

I made a separate component called "LogoTitle" for that logo and then tried importing that logo into my Homescreen.js folder. This is the second image I use since I thought the first image may be corrupt. I also created a src folder with an assets and images file for that folder. Under the images folder, that's where I have the logo.  Below are the links so you can see how I have the code.  Any help is appreciated. Below is the code for my image to appear. I also have two still images attached so you can see my src folder and the homescreen.js folder.

```
class LogoTitle extends React.Component {
  render() {
   return (
    <Image 
      source={require("../../assets/images/america.png")}
      style={{ width: 30, height: 30 }}
    />
  );
 }
}
```

**LogoTitle.js folder**

[image]

**Homescreen.js folder**

[image]

Comment: How do you want your header to look like?

Comment: Hi @CarlosAbraham, I was trying to get a little soccer ball to appear in the middle of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can always create your own `<Header/>` component. I created a simple Header component to show you how you can accomplish adding a background image to your header. See the snack [@abranhe/stackoverflow-56729412](https://snack.expo.io/@abranhe/stackoverflow-56729412)

**Header.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Dimensions, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';

export default class Header extends Component {
  renderContent() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.content}>
        <View style={styles.left}>{this.props.left}</View>
        <View style={styles.center}>{this.props.center}</View>
        <View style={styles.right}>{this.props.right}</View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderHeaderWithImage() {
    return (
      <ImageBackground style={styles.container} source={this.props.imageSource}>
        {this.renderContent()}
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }

  renderHeaderWithoutImage() {
    return (
      <View style={[{ backgroundColor: '#f8f8f8' }, styles.container]}>
        {this.renderContent()}
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.image
      ? this.renderHeaderWithImage()
      : this.renderHeaderWithoutImage();
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    top: 0,
    position: 'absolute',
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    backgroundColor: '#f8f8f8',
    borderBottom: 1,
    borderColor: '#f8f8f8',
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.5,
  },
  content: {
    width: '100%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.03,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.045,
  },
  left: {
    marginHorizontal: 5,
  },
  center: {
    marginHorizontal: 5,
  },
  right: {
    marginHorizontal: 5,
  },
});
```

and then on when you want to use the **Header** component you can set the `image` prop to `true`, eg:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import Header from './components/Header';

export default () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Header
        image
        imageSource={{ uri: 'https://yourimage.png' }}
        left={<Ionicons name="md-arrow-round-back" size={25} />}
        center={<Text>Projects</Text>}
        right={<Ionicons name="ios-camera" size={25} />}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

[image]

and then if you set the `image` prop to `false` you will remove the image from the background.

```js
<Header
  image={false}
  imageSource={{ uri: 'https://yourimage.png' }}
  left={<Ionicons name="md-arrow-round-back" size={25} />}
  center={<Text>Projects</Text>}
  right={<Ionicons name="ios-camera" size={25} />}
/>
```

[image]

> **UPDATE** after the question author asked how he could put a soccer ball in the center of the header

You can just add the image to the center prop like this:

```js
<Header
  left={<Ionicons name="md-arrow-round-back" size={25} />}
  center={<Image source={{ uri: 'soccer-img' }} style={{ width: 25, height: 25 }} />}
  right={<Ionicons name="ios-camera" size={25} />}
/>
```

then you would have something like this:

[image]

Check the snack: https://snack.expo.io/@abranhe/stackoverflow-57083909